# Trying tocall a jquery function from server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call a jQuery function from the server using script manager but I'm not able to make the call. How should it be called? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    BindDummyRow();
  }        
  TW12HVGI();
}

void TW12HVGI()
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "dynamicForm();", true);
}
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // $(document).ready(function () {  
  $(function dynamicForm() {
    $("#openForm").click(function () {   
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: Just a slightly pedantic note, but worth the distinction I think: Technically you can't _call_ a Javascript function from C#, because function never executes on the server, and your C# code never sees the result of it. What you're doing is telling the browser to _render_ that bit of script into the finished HTML page which is the output of the C# code. It's the _browser_ which ends up running that script. That script causes the other bit of Javascript to execute _in the browser_. C# and Javascript do not interact in any way, except that your C# can be used to _create_ some Javascript

Comment: Anyway for this simple example, what you're doing is totally unnecessary. Just write `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#openForm").click(function () {   
    });
  });
</script>` somewhere in your page, and jQuery will ensure the the click handler is added when the page is finished loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you've defined `dynamicForm()` as the function you provide to the jQuery document.ready handler, so it's not in the correct scope. Try this instead:

```
function dynamicForm() {
  $("#openForm").click(function () {   
    // do something...
  });
}
```

Also note that you could make this a lot simpler by just calling `dynamicForm()` within your JS and removing the unnecessary `RegisterStartupScript()` from your server side logic.

Comment: but if changed the function as you mentioned                                   function dynamicForm() {
  $("#openForm").click(function () {   
    // do something...
  });                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                    then $("#openForm").click(function ()  was not working as it was previously

Comment: Then call `dynamicForm()` from within the document.ready event handler too.